# Knockout if binding causes issue with "perfect-scrollbar.js"

Tags: knockout.js, scrollbar

I am trying to use the "perfect-scrollbar.js" http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/ on my MVC 5 app which uses knockout.  The problem I have is that I have the following section in code (typically  MVC 5 SPA Template code, I have left out the unwanted stuff for brevity)

```
           <div data-bind="if: loggedIn" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <span class="navbar-text nofloat">                                
                           <div id="description" class="wrapper"> <!--This is the area that is supposed to scroll-->
                           <div>
                           <p>The command takes options applicable</p>
                           <p>The command takes options applicable</p>
                           <p>The command takes options applicable</p>
                           <p>The command takes options applicable</p>

                           </div>
                           </div>                               
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

The javascript I have is

```
$('#description').perfectScrollbar();
```

The problem is that the scroll bars never appear but as soon as I remove the **data-bind="if: loggedIn"** section from the code then it works fine (the scroll bars appear).  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Its the same problem with the other 3rd party scroll bar components such as iScroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` binding removes and recreates its children nodes when the attached observable changes.

So if you call `$('#description').perfectScrollbar();` only once, then the next time the `if` binding reevaluates, your `description` will be removed/recreated so you will lose the scrolling.

A workaround would be to use the [`visible` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) instead of the `if` because it only hides the nodes and does not remove them, but maybe this is not what you want.

So a more proper solution would be to create a very simple [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) which applies the `perfectScrollbar` to a given node:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.perfectScrollbar = {
    init: function(element) {        
        $(element).perfectScrollbar();   
    }
}
```

And use it in your view:

```
<div id="description" data-bind="perfectScrollbar: {}" class="wrapper">
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyw94/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your custom binding handler saved me a lot of work :)